# SignalR returns error - Unexpected end when deserializing object

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I have simple project, where I'm using signalR, When page loads, signalR scripts are loaded succefully, however right after that, call to

> http://localhost:24634/signalr/signalr/connect?transport=foreverFrame&connectionId=dca2db9c-b16a-4b96-96dc-9a6b187b6d9e&connectionData=[{"name":"notifier"}]&tid=5&frameId=1

returns 500 Internal Server Error, I checked this request in fiddler, error message says

> Unexpected end when deserializing object.

Here's my Hub Definitin

```
[HubName("notifier")]
    public class PublishingNotifier: Hub
    {   
        [HubMethodName("send")]
        public void SendMessage(string message)
        {
            Clients.getNotification(message);
        }
    }
```

and here's my client code

```
$(function () {

            var publishingNotifier = $.connection.notifier;

            publishingNotifier.getNotification = function (message) {
                // do something
            };

            $('input[type=submit][id*=cmsB_ChangeStatusToPublishedTop]').on('click', function (e) {
                // do something else
            });

            $.connection.hub.start();
        });
```

Any ideas what can be cause of this error ?

**EDIT**
Here is Stack Trace information

> [JsonSerializationException: Unexpected end when deserializing object.
>   Line 1, position 2.]
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CheckedRead(JsonReader
>   reader) +75
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader
>   reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member,
>   Object existingValue) +48
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader
>   reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member,
>   Object existingValue) +86
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList(IWrappedCollection
>   wrappedList, JsonReader reader, String reference, JsonArrayContract
>   contract) +635
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.<>c_*DisplayClass1.<CreateAndPopulateList>b*_0(IList
>   l, Boolean isTemporaryListReference) +124
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.CollectionUtils.CreateAndPopulateList(Type
>   listType, Action`2 populateList) +546
>
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateAndPopulateList(JsonReader
>   reader, String reference, JsonArrayContract contract) +101
>
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader
>   reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member,
>   Object existingValue, String reference) +62
>
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader
>   reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member,
>   Object existingValue) +113
>
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueNonProperty(JsonReader
>   reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonConverter
>   converter) +118
>
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader
>   reader, Type objectType) +125
>
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader,
>   Type objectType) +311
>
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type,
>   JsonSerializerSettings settings) +107
>
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value,
>   JsonSerializerSettings settings) +66
>
>   SignalR.JsonNetSerializer.Parse(String json) +57
>
>   SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.CreateConnection(String connectionId,
>   IEnumerable`1 groups, IRequest request) +140
>   SignalR.PersistentConnection.ProcessRequestAsync(HostContext context)
>   +227    SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.ProcessRequestAsync(HostContext context) +120
>   SignalR.Hosting.AspNet.AspNetHandler.ProcessRequestAsync(HttpContextBase
>   context) +463
>   SignalR.Hosting.AspNet.HttpTaskAsyncHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +68
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +301    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

**EDIT2:**

One more note - from the page that runs without any errors, requested url looks like this

> localhost:24634/signalr/signalr/connect?transport=foreverFrame&connectionId=98e6d5b3-b164-4013-92c2-418aa6254f9e&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22notifier%22%7D%5D&tid=7&frameId=1

and the failing request url looks like this

> localhost:24634/signalr/signalr/connect?transport=foreverFrame&connectionId=9b398750-99d6-4188-88b5-b41ad9eb82d5&connectionData=[{"name":"notifier"}]&tid=1&frameId=1

As you may notice, the ways connectionData query string parameter is defined in urls are different, in particular, for the first url, connectionData has been url encoded the query string value, and the second query string parameter has been html encoded. I've looked into request headers, failing request Content-Type is text/html, and the second request's Content-Type: application/json.

**EDIT 3:**

I've found where connectionData get's parsed, in jquery.signalR-0.5.3.js file, here's code that actually encodes connectionData value

```
if (connection.data) {
  qs += "&connectionData=" + window.escape(connection.data);
}
```

as you can see, window.escape() is responsible for encoding connectionData, but, if I debug this code, I can see that window.escape(connection.data) indeed html encodes connection.data instead of url encoding. But this is happening only on one page, on anothers, it works as expected.

Comment: When exactly does the exception occur? Do you invoke the server side `SendMessage` hub method from a client, or?

Comment: No, I do nothing, just waiting for page to load. In the fiddler I can see that page fails to make signalR requests, moreover, I had to have this logic ( client-side ) on few pages, and this type of exception occurs only on one of them.

Comment: From what I can read in various similar questions, people have been experiencing problems with the Newtonsoft JSON serializer - you could try installing a newer or older version and see if it makes any difference. Further, are you sure that you cannot reproduce this error on any client? Which browsers are the clients using? Do you see any errors in the browsers' console?

Comment: Well, actually I tried to reinstall Newtonsoft, and even tried different versions, nothing helped. I can't reproduce this, I've created similar project, and it runs as expected. As I mentioned, this exact same code works on another page within same project, but on this page, it fails. The problem is, I can't see when, who makes call to JSON.NET API ( as seen in stack trace ) to somehow have more clear understanding, what may cause the problem. And there is no any error message in console, I tried all major browsers ( IE9+, Chrome/Firefox ), results are same.

Comment: What about SignalR - which versions of their client side lib have you tried?

Comment: signalR-0.5.3 and signalR-0.5.1

Comment: You write that: "as you can see, window.escape() is responsible for encoding connectionData, but, if I debug this code, I can see that window.escape(connection.data) indeed html encodes connection.data instead of url encoding. But this is happening only on one page, on anothers, it works as expected." <-- have you checked that you do not have any other JS lib on that particular page that might re-define `window.escape`?

Comment: @LasseChristiansen-sw_lasse yes, you're right, I've excluded all the js developed by our team, and problem was still there, the problem is, we're using so much 3rd party controls, that are generating their own js files, that even if windows.escape() were overriden in one of them, I wouldn't be able to change those scripts, so I just find a workaround, I've modified jquery.signalR.js file itself, and handle connection.data url encoding myself. Thanks for help thou !

Comment: Great! Glad I could help! :) I have added an answer to the question that sums up the solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up, the problem turned out to be that `window.escape` was overridden by a third party JS library. This caused `window.escape` to behave differently than "normal" causing SignalR to fail as a side-effect.

So basically - when these "weird" issues occur - check if you have included libraries that "interfere" and make sure to use proper namespacing ( e.g. using the module pattern ) to avoid this issue.

Answer (score -1):

BUG

I do not know if this could help, but I had the error "unexpected end when deserializing object message c #", when I was trying to deserialize my json.
**It happened to me sometimes, sometimes not. I do not know what it depends on.**

My json was like that:

https://api.myjson.com/bins/l83m8

Debugging the Xamarin App on visual studio 2019 gives me the following:

```
var content = await _client.GetStringAsync(Connection.URL);
invitaciones = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(content);
```

The variable "content" sometimes gives me https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/2lss and sometimes gives me https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/2lsu.

If you look very carefully, you are gonna release that both are different, only because, the first one is missing a } just in the end.

If you deserialize both with https://www.unserialize.me/ tool, and then validate the result on https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ (default options), you are gonna see that the first one isn't valid, and the second is valid.

**Solution:**

Add a validation: if the string content (json) don't ends with }, put a } on the end.I know it's pretty silly, but solves my problem.

```
 var content = await _client.GetStringAsync(Connection.URL);
 if (!content.EndsWith("}"))
     content = content + "}";
 invitaciones = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(content);
```

Packages: Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.2, Xamarin.Forms 3.6.0.344457 .